# Changed Lines of code under Clearcase

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I am using clear-case as version control. Usually when working with the maintenance projects it's required to count the changed lines from existing code. How we can do this under clear-case. It would be helpful if you can give the details of the command tool and parameters to get the changes made within a particular period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by testing the [slc perl script](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/bradapp/clearperl/sclc.html) which does count changed lines:

> So if I want to count the changed lines of code between what is in my view and what was on the REL1.0.0 label, I would do the following:

```
$ sclc -fromver REL1.0.0 *.[ch]
```

> And if I wanted to count the changed lines of code between files on my /main/rel1/mychanges branch and the REL1.0.0 baseline label they where branched off from, I would use:

```
$ sclc -fromver REL1.0.0 -tover .../mychanges/LATEST *.[ch]
```

> If I wanted to see the difference in lines of code for files on to different labels I would do something like:

```
$ sclc -fromver REL1.0.0 -tover REL2.0.0 *.[ch]
```

---

There is no "native" solution though, and [this thread summarizes the situation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=14280785).